# Run periodic task in background mode on iOS8

Tags: swift, background, ios8

I want to run a periodic task when my application is in background mode on iOS8. I wrote a following code in swift but failing. Can some point out what is wrong?

Here is my code from AppDelegate.swift

```
let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND,0)

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    println("did enter background")
    dispatch_async(self.backgroundQueue, myBackgroundTask)
}

func myBackgroundTask() {
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.5)
    println("this is back ground task")
    dispatch_async(self.backgroundQueue, myBackgroundTask)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone told me calling "beginBackgroundTaskWithName" is the answer.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    println("did enter background")
    application.beginBackgroundTaskWithName("myBgTask", expirationHandler: nil)
    dispatch_async(self.backgroundQueue, myBackgroundTask)
}

func myBackgroundTask() {
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.5)
    println("this is back ground task")
    dispatch_async(self.backgroundQueue, myBackgroundTask)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use:

```
dispatch_async(self.backgroundQueue, Selector("myBackgroundTask"))
```

I am not sure if this is the way, but in swift passing a func as a parameter is usually like this.